# Do I have to use all days in Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, germany

Suppose I have Schengen multi visa type C, issued by Germany for 1 year with amount of days, allowing me to stay equal to 20. This is the first visa in my passport. Will I face any penalties on the next year application if this year I will use less than 20 days?

Comment: @pnuts I actually don't have it now, this is for invitation application. The person who invites is close relative.

Comment: @pnuts yes, indeed it would be type C.

Comment: @pnuts No, no schengen visas, no other visas at all.

Comment: Is this a hypothetical?  Because if the visa is granted for longer than 6 months, then the number of days is supposed to be 90.  The visa you describe therefore should not exist.

Comment: @phoog yes, this is hypothetical, my question was if there any penalties if not all days in visa are used, It does not matter what is the number 90 or 20. Say I have visa for N days, I used only M, where M < N. Will I face any problems in future?

Comment: @nikitoz: Actually, whether the number is 90 or 20 _does_ matter (except that the end answer happens to be the same in both cases), because when the "duration of stay" field says 90, it means _90 days out of any 180_, not 90 days in total over the lifetime of the visa. [This is a special rule for multiple-entry visas with a validity of more than 6 months].

Answer (score 1):

When you apply for the visa, you submit a premise for your trip and an itinerary. You can *adjust* your travel plans slightly later on, but itinerary **must** be truthful at the time you make it.

The visa may be granted for a few more days at either end. If so you are not required to extend your trip. In fact, it is your responsibility to abide by the terms of your visa, and it never hurts to have a day or two extra in reserve.

Comment: @pnuts, multiple-entry visa tend to be for a long period but I thought they don't have to be.